# Deltaspike TransactionStrategy Alternative Ambiguous dependencies

Tags: java, cdi, deltaspike, weld-se

I'm defining the **TransactionStrategy** in **apache-deltaspike.properties**, using Global Alternatives configuration:

```
globalAlternatives.org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.spi.transaction.TransactionStrategy=org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy
```

My **beans.xml** has the **deltaspike-data** module Interceptor only:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                           http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <interceptors>
        <class>org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

But I'm being hit by the exception below, which doesn't make any sense to me:

```
WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type TransactionStrategy with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor.transactionStrategy
  at org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor.transactionStrategy(TransactionalInterceptor.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

Apparently the **BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy** alternative is being activated by default. Cause when I remove the Global alternative definition I can see that **deltaspike-data** module uses the **BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy**.

### Dependencies Versions:

- weld-se-shaded: **3.0.6.Final**
- deltaspike: **1.9.3**

Any ideas of how to get around it? I need to use the **ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a work-around: excluding the **BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy** from the beans scan.

I'm doing this in **beans.xml** using the **WELD** specific XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:weld="http://jboss.org/schema/weld/beans">
    <weld:scan>
        <weld:exclude name="org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.BeanManagedUserTransactionStrategy"/>
    </weld:scan>
    <interceptors>
        <class>org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

By doing this I'm giving up on portability, meaning this will only work with **WELD**.